# Spring Security config ignored while running on Docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-security

I dockerized my simple spring boot application and I started by addind a repo, check that the connection works (and it does) and a simple controller for a simple model. Also added a controller for health checks. I permit all by a configuration, but everytime i try to access it, it redirects me to localhost:8080/login. Why is that?

Also if i run this project as it is (not as a docker image), it works.

My config (i use this because WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter seems to be deprecated) :

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: spring-backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/local_db
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=none
      - JAR_FILE=./build/libs/*.jar

  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: local_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=local_db
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre
ARG JAR_FILE=./build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable httpBasic.

`httpBasic.withDefaults()`

activates spring security.

see:

[HttpBasicConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/HttpBasicConfigurer.html)

Comment: Still the same... And it's weird cause if i don't run the image, but the project locally it works ok.

Here's my config after your comment:

http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                );

Comment: `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()` --remove that httpBasic disable.

Comment: same :/ nothing changed.

Comment: fixed, there was an issue with the build. It was using an older version. Thank you!